# Need a list of all units available in quantities python package

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to get a list of all the units that are predefined in the python quantities package. Something like this:

```
from quantities import units as u

myList = u.length.list(everything defined with UnitLength)
```

and the result would be:

```
myList = ['m','meter','metre,'mi','au',...]
```

I want to do that for all the unit types that they define in the package.  Any idea how to do that without parsing the actual source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from quantities import units

unit_symbols = [u.symbol for _, u in units.__dict__.items()
    if isinstance(u, type(units.deg))]
```

Check the docs, maybe this list is exported.

Comment: Thanks, Yakym.  This is exactly what I needed.  Turns out I need both the symbols and the names in one big list so the suggestion from Erik Bailey is useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
from quantities import units as u

myList = [unit for unit in dir(u.length) 
          if type(getattr(u.length, unit)) is u.UnitLength]
```

The downside is it's not applicable to the other unit types, as you need to know the type of each.

Answer (score 0):

Yakym, great response.  thegoodson, depending on whether or not you want the abbreviated or non-abbreviated versions, use the first (dumped to _ in Yakim's example) to get the non-abbreviated list.  I guess a more complete way (to get both) would be:

```
from quantities import units as u

unit_symbols = [foo.symbol for _, foo in u.__dict__.items() if isinstance(foo, type(u.m))]
unit_names = [bar for bar, foo in u.__dict__.items() if isinstance(foo, type(u.m))]
```

Comment: why have separate lists for the names and values? why not just make a dict?  `all_units = {bar:foo for bar,foo in u.__dict__.items() if isinstance(foo, type(u.m))}`

Comment: Even better!  Love it!

Answer (score -1):

This useful module can help you: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units.